# Swift Combine: Waiting until subscribed to generate values

Tags: swift, combine

I'm trying to write a custom publisher that generates some values. Something like this:

```swift
class MyPublisher: Publisher {

    typealias Output = Int
    typealias Failure = Never

    private let subject = PassThroughSubject<Int, Never>()

    func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S: Subscriber, S.Failure == Failure, S.Input == Output {
        subject.receive(subscriber: subscriber)
        startSending()
    }

    func startSending() {
        subject.send(1)
        subject.send(2)
        subject.send(3)
        subject.send(completion: .finished)
    }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to call `startSending()` automatically after a subscribing attaches, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

I've just been reading about `ConnectablePublisher` and was wondering if that might help, but I'm not sure how.

Has anyone tried something like this? How did you do it?

Comment: I don’t know the exact answer, it’s been a while since I’ve worked with this, but I can say confidently: the WWDC keynotes are some of the best documentation on combine, particularly conceptual things like this, about how exactly publisher life times work. I’d suggest you have a watch through those, they’re pretty great!

Comment: You're not actually doing that which is the job of a custom publisher. See my https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/publishers/publisherscustom.html.

Comment: @matt Can't we just take the PassthroughSubject `subject` and do a `subject.receive(subscriber: subscriber)` in function receive in order to make this a complete custom publisher?

Comment: This does what you're trying to do. As soon as it receives a subscriber, it will startSending and the subscriber will receive the updates. BUT, since you're also sending completion, only the first subscriber will receive the updates.

Comment: When you add a subscriber to your publisher, `startSending` will be called and the subscriber receives 3 values, then "finished". Subsequent subscribers only receive a "finished" - because your internal subject is finished. Is this what you want? (ups, basically said the same as farzadshbfn ;)

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what you're _really_ trying to do. If the goal were really to publish 1, then 2, then 3, then complete, you don't need to make a custom publisher to do that. If you want better help, ask a more realistic question.

Comment: Thanks everyone. This is a very simplified version of the real code I'm working with so it does look a little contrived. As I said, what I'm trying to do is work out the best way to initiate sending, but only after a subscriber is attached. Hope this helps and thanks again. It's all food for thought.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I have messed about with a full on custom publisher as per your blog post previously, but I've generally found that using an internal subject like this solves most situations. I might still end up going the whole hog though :-)

Comment: Just as info: as, matt already pointed out, your final goal is not clear. The above custom publisher can be simulated with just `[1, 2, 3].publisher`   :)

Comment: "initiate sending, but only after a subscriber is attached." ... have you looked into [`Deferred`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/deferred)

Answer (score 0):

As a continuation of this. One of the changes I've been experimenting with is to locally declared the subject instead of having it as a class variable. I think that solves the issue some raised about multiple subscribers.

```swift
public func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S: Subscriber, S.Failure == Failure, S.Input == Output {
    let subject = PassthroughSubject<Int, Error>()
    defaultValueSubject.receive(subscriber: subscriber)
    startSending(to: subject)
}

func startSending(to subject: PassThroughSubject<Int>) {
    subject.send(1)
    subject.send(2)
    subject.send(3)
    subject.send(completion: .finished)
}
```

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment / addendum to the question?